# Fail to encode/decode view model array

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, decode, encode

I'm learning how to use MVVM to make a little project recently, and I've encountered some problems when I want to store the information.

Is it possible to make this Observable class conform to codable? Because when I tried to use userDefault to store a view model array in my home page, the system warned me that the view model does not conform to codable. However, when I go to my view model and mark this one `var badHabitInfo: Observable<BadHabitModel> = Observable(nil)`, the warning disappeared. So I think if I make the Observable class conform to codable, it should be ok to encode/decode my view model array.
Does anyone can help? Thanks in advance!

```
class Observable<T> {
    var value: T? {
        didSet{
            listener?(value)
        }
    }
    
    init(_ value: T?) {
        self.value = value
    }
    
    private var listener: ((T?) -> Void)?
    
    func bind(listener: @escaping (T?) -> Void) {
        listener(value)
        self.listener = listener
    }
    
}
```

This is my view model array in the home page.

```
var badHabits: [AddQuitItemViewModel] = []
```

Comment: I am sure you can make it conform to Codable but it isn’t your view model you should persist but your model.

Comment: I kind of understand what you mean. I originally pass the view model around, so should I pass the model instead, and make it equal to badHabitInfo.value?

Comment: Thanks, I got the solution! Just like what you said, store model instead of view model!